# What do I need to do on a minimal CentOS 8 installation to receive root's emails?

Tags: centos, email, root, centos8

I've tried searching but all of the results seem to be about setting up an actual mail server.  I just want the simplest solution.

I've added my email address to the bottom of `/etc/aliases`.

I've had the server a week or more now, and I note that `/var/spool/mail/root` doesn't exist?  Why would that be, I feel there should be a smattering of emails in there by now.  `/var/spool/mail/codemonkey` does exist (but is empty).

I (optimistically) tried `dnf install mail`, but that package doesn't exist.  a `dnf search` shows `sendmail` and `mailx`, along with a million other things.  What's the right package?
Thanks

Comment: Did you run `newaliases` after you updated your /etc/aliases file?
Have you checked your logs (/var/log/mail and /var/log/messages)?
Sendmail is probably going to be your "fastest and simplest", btw.

Comment: I was about to edit the question to add postfix into the mix.  But of mailx/postfix/sendmail you think the latter is the right choice?  Why can't I find any eli5 tutorial outlining this crucial server-setup step?  `newaliases` gives me `command not found` - I'll google that now.  `/var/log/mail` doesn't exist, but I do have `/var/log/maillog` which has some entries.

Comment: OK, `sendmail` installed, `newaliases` (comes as part of sendmail, I now know) run.  Anything else?  How can I test it's working?

Comment: `sendmail me@mydomain.com < test` gives `stat=Deferred: Connection refused by [127.0.0.1]` in `/var/log/maillog`

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

`echo "Subject: sendmail test" | sendmail -v me@domain.com`

This will give you a verbose output of sendmail.

Comment: I appreciate you taking the time to respond, but I gave up with sendmail, installed postfix and it worked essentially immediately.